# php xpath sort alphabetically by field

Tags: php, sorting, alphabetical

I'd like to have a more accurate alphabetical sort for xpath. My current system only sorts the first two characters of the field... I'd like it the order the whole field if possible.

```
foreach(range('A','Z') AS $firstletter) {
     foreach(range('a','z') AS $secondletter) {
              $letters = $firstletter.$secondletter;
              if($item->xpath("/Entries
                                  /Entry[
                                     starts-with(
                                        Field42,
                                        '".$letters."'
                                     )
                                   and 
                                     Field380 = 'Okay'
                                  ]")) {
```

The Field42 entries are lastnames (ie Brown, Brownstein, Brownwood, Byrnes,..)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll be able to sort using XPath *(its goal being to select data -- not sort it)*.

So, why not do it in pure-PHP :

- First, load all of your nodes to a PHP array
- And, then, sort that array using one of the functions provided by PHP

  - Such as [`sort`](https://www.php.net/sort), [`asort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php), [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), ...

Comment: +1 Properly speaking, [node sets](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Introduction) are _"unordered collection of nodes without duplicates"_