# use wildcard to match attribute in xpath

Tags: asp.net, xpath

I am working on an asp.net application based on .net 2.0.

And I meet some problems when I process the XML.

Suppose I have XML like this:

```
<person name="xxxyx" age="32" />

<person name="zzz" age="32" />

<person name="yyyxx" age="32" />
```

Now I want to select the person whose name contains `yx`

How do I use xpath to implement it?

I only know this expression will match the person whose name is exactly "yx":

```
"//person[name='yx'"]"
```

How to make the fuzzy search?

BTW, any idea to sort the matched person by the specified attribute like "name"?

Comment: How should the sorting be done, does this refer to an XSL transformation?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607592/xpath-and-wildcards/5607636#5607636

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like @Utkanos suggested `//person[contains(@name, 'yx')]` should match the nodes you want.

XPath itself is, at least at my knowledge, not capable and not intended to provide order on nodes, but instead returns node-sets which are "unordered collection of nodes without duplicates" (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598641/948404) and comments). However in version 2.0 there might be changes to this [2](http://www.ximeco.org/Xime/XPathCanSortHlousek.pdf) with which I am not familiar.

Assuming the sorting should be done in an XSL transformation you could use `<xsl:sort />` like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//person[contains(@name, 'yx')]">
    <xsl:sort select="@name" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

There are some more attributes on `<xsl:sort />` documented here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#sorting

Comment: It remains true in XPath 2.0 (and indeed 3.0) that standalone XPath has no sorting capability - you need to go to XSLT or XQuery.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `contains()` function.

```
//person[contains(@name, 'yx')]
```

Also, note you need `@` in front of `name` since it's an attribute.

**[Demo](http://www.xmlplayground.com/8aC98G).**